# Can a sudo session be reused after logging out?

Tags: security, sudo, session

The `sudo` command remembers for a while that I entered my password, so that I don't need to re-enter it every time. I know that I can delete this "session" using `sudo -k`.

Now, if I was logged in via ssh, used sudo, and then logged out without running `sudo -k`. Could someone who gained access to my account before the sudo password re-entry timeout somehow use sudo without entering a password? I know it doesn't work when you just open a new ssh session, presumably because it uses a different pseudo-terminal, but there might be a different way.

And if it is possible, what can I do against it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, yes, a sudo session can be reused if you log out and someone else logs in *as you* on the same terminal. [As you found in the documentation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325762), sudo detects and rejects this sometimes, but not always.

If someone logs in as you, then the game is pretty much lost. They can plant a backdoor on your account and, in the worst case for the attacker, snipe your password and piggyback on your sudo access the next time you use sudo. So the answer to “what can I do against it?” is “nothing”, and more importantly the answer to “what should I do against it?” is “nothing”. It doesn't make any threat worse.

Comment: I think setting `Defaults timestamp_timeout=0` could reduce the exposure -- if only to an unattended open session where the attacker does not know your password. If they can log in as you, game over.

Answer (score 3):

**At least on Linux and OS X systems, cached timestamps will not survive logging out.**

The answer is in [`man sudoers`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.2/sudoers.man.html), not in `man sudo`, which is why I didn't find it at first:

> Since time stamp files live in the file system, they can outlive a user's login session. As a result, a user may be able to login, run a command with sudo after authenticating, logout, login again, and run sudo without authenticating so long as the time stamp file's modification time is within 5 minutes (or whatever the timeout is set to in sudoers). When the tty_tickets option is enabled, the time stamp has per-tty granularity but still may outlive the user's session. On Linux systems where the devpts filesystem is used, Solaris systems with the devices filesystem, as well as other systems that utilize a devfs filesystem that monotonically increase the inode number of devices as they are created (such as Mac OS X), sudoers is able to determine when a tty-based time stamp file is stale and will ignore it. Administrators should not rely on this feature as it is not universally available.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` remembers the password per terminal session. 
If you logged out (either because you logged out yourself or your session has terminated for some reason) there is no problem.

The only problem could be a `screen` session where you used `sudo` in.

But if you are afraid of any issues, you can simply configure `sudo` not to cache the password.

Comment: But how does it discern different terminal sessions reliably? By pty? By PID? What if the PTY or PID are reused? Is there any reference about this?